# How to make checkboxes selected programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created custom control which contains checkboxlist as

```
      <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklLineOfAuthority"   RepeatColumns="3" RepeatLayout="Table"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="false" runat="server">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

In its ascx.cs file has a function like

```
    public void FillLineOfAuthorityForProduct(string loastring)
    {
        //let's us consider loastring contains 

        string loastring = "Casualty, Credit, Motor Club";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        LineOfAuthorityBL bl = new LineOfAuthorityBL(SessionContext.SystemUser);
        bl.FetchAll(ds);
        chklLineOfAuthority.DataSource = ds.Tables[bl.SqlEntityX];
        chklLineOfAuthority.DataTextField = "LineOfAuthorityX";
        chklLineOfAuthority.DataBind();
        ds = null;
        bl = null;

        string[] arrGroup = loastring.Split(',');

            foreach (object obj in arrGroup)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < chklLineOfAuthority.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (chklLineOfAuthority.Items[i].Value == obj.ToString())
                    {
                        chklLineOfAuthority.Items[i].Selected = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Then the output should be like

[image]

I mean Casualty, Motor Club, Credit checkboxes should be checked. The above code is not working.

Comment: you split the string by ","s and whitespaces may be contained by the string parts. are you sure that the if statement in the for loop gets true value?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your `foreach` and inspect the value of `obj`.

Comment: Could you please compare both questions... both are totally different...

Comment: When the method is executed? Page_Load? Are you using ASP.Net Ajax?

Comment: Do you use UpdatePanel? Is it configured for always update or conditional?

Comment: Yes it is used in all pages no conditions

Comment: If it is set to update conditionally you must use UpdatePanelName.Update() after setting your checkboxlist items' state.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` loop to loop through the `CheckboxList` and then compare each `ListItem` value with `obj.ToString()` (This will replace your `for` loop. Something like below:

```
foreach (ListItem itm in chklLineOfAuthority.Items)
{
    if (itm.Value == obj.ToString())
    {
        itm.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is comparing all strings properly. But the checkboxes is not getting selected

Comment: I can see two things in the code: first your string loastring is "Casualty, Credit, Motor Club" change it to string "Casualty,Credit,Motor Club" i.e. remove spaces after comma. Two, change `foreach (object obj in arrGroup)` to `foreach (string str in arrGroup)` since arrGroup is already declared as a string array. This still may not solve your problem but at least the code would be proper.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
foreach (object obj in arrGroup)
{                
     chklLineOfAuthority.Items.FindByText(obj.ToString()).Selected = true;   
}
```